# cannot edit form input in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to edit form input values in reactjs. I have tried the two code below but the form input could not allow me to edit or typing new data

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

function handleChange_username(event) {
  setUsername({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
}
```

**or**

```
 function handleChange_username(event) {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  }
```

**here is the input**

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value={record[cRec].username}  onChange={handleChange_username}/>
```

Comment: What is that record variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several problems in the `changeFunction`, and also in the `html` element:

```
    const Comp = props => {
      const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    
      function handleChange_username(event) {
        const { target = {} } = event || {};
        const { value = "" } = target || {};
        setUsername(value);
      }
      return  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value={username}  onChange={handleChange_username}/>
    }
```

If you want to use the: `setUsername({[name]: value});`, you have to provide a an object in the state, not a string like here `const [username, setUsername] = useState("");`.

**Advanced:**

```
    const Comp = props => {
      const [state, setState] = useState({});
    
      function handleChange(event) {
        const { target = {} } = event || {};
        const { value = "", name = "" } = target || {};
        setState(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value });
      }

      const { username = "", email = "" } = state || {};
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value={email}  onChange={handleChange}/>
          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value={username}  onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things.

1. If you are going to use a object instead of a string for the username, you should do:

   ```
    const [username, setUsername] = useState({});
   ```
2. In order for the input to show the change in your input, you need to bind the value attribute of your username state.

   ```
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value={username}  onChange={(e)=> setUsername({username: event.target.value})} />
   ```

or in the function handleChange_username, modify the record[cRec].username variable.

Hope that helps!